# Webpack ES6 Module Bundling w/ Typescript and Babel

Tags: typescript, gulp, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

I have a simple setup where I am using webpack-stream to use web pack in gulp.
I am trying to transpire my typescript to javascript and bundle all of my modules into one file using es6 modules.

My setup (I have a .babelrc file set to es2015):

```
  return gulp.src('./app/index.ts')
    .pipe(webpack({
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
      },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      },
      output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build));
```

The result of this setup just transpiles my typescript for index.ts and keeps the imports in the file. What am I doing wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The configuration for loaders should look like this:

```
loaders: [
  {
    loader: 'babel!ts',
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```

This ensures that babel runs before typescript does.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have all your npm dependencies:

`"babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5"`

I believe you also need to specify which preset to use, so update your babel loader from this:

`{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }`

to this:

`{
       loader: 'babel',
       test: /\.js$/, 
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       query: {
           presets: ['es2015']
       }
    }`

Comment: I have a .babelrc file with my preset set to es2015, and tried putting it in my webpack configuration and got the same result. Instead of installing babel I installed babel-core, I think this is the new way to install babel. Regardless my output is a file only including my index.ts code with import statements.

Comment: oh sorry, I missed that. You should try putting the babel loader in a separate `post-loaders` section. [Check it out here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders).

Comment: Putting babel loader in the postLoaders gives me the same result.